# Need help designing this using the ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am new to ConstraintLayout and trying to achieve the view as attached. Even with Chain, no luck. Maybe I am missing something?

[image]

Comment: Chain the three TextViews together and set app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread” . If those icons are separate ImageViews, just align the end of each ImageView to the start of each TextView. The ImageViews should not be a part of the chain.

Comment: @EricBachhuber, there is one more view on the left. It is a huge image.

Comment: Same concept, but instead of your chain starting at parent start, it should start at the end of that ImageView. So the left-most TextView should be chained to ImageView end (the ImageView with the horse). I can write a code example if you need.

Comment: @EricBachhuber, I am not sure what you mean by starting a chain at ImageView. can you elaborate? Code sample would be of great help as well. Thank you.

Comment: Let's say your ImageView has an ID horse_image and the three TextViews you want to chain are text_1, text_2, text_3. First, you would need to chain text_1, text_2, text_3 together (no other Views should be in this chain). Then, set text_1's start constraint to `layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/horse_image"`. text_3's end constraint should be `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`. After that, just set the chain style to `spread` or `spread_inside`, and then align your icons as needed.

Comment: https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html Is a resource you might want to look at, it goes a lot more in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplyfy your alignment with `Constraint Layout`.

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Android"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <view
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="100"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="100"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="100"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers. You can do it with Linear Layout You can use Linear Layout as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

There is absolutely no need for `ConstraintLayout` for such a simple task.

Even Google's docs say `ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups).`

Just use three `LinearLayout` inside one another `LinearLayout`. Much simpler and uses less resources